# NativeWebView ANE from distriqt to use with Starling

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, webview, distriqt

I would like to use NativeWebView ANE from Distriqt in my iOS/Android App that I am developing in AS3 and Starling. The problem is that I don't find any example to implement it in this way or any guidelines to do it so. The only example provided is with Flash sprite exclusively.

I would appreciate if someone could please give me a hand with this issue.

Comment: What you said does not make too much sense. That web view doesn't need a Flash Sprite for anything, it needs a Rectangle and display on top of everything. Starling has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I will try as you suggest. I was afraid that i might commit a mistake. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The WebView is displayed as a native UI component and sits outside the display list and Stage3D content.

Native UI components are placed above the AIR stage and run as a separate component to your AIR content. This means that you cannot layer AIR content over a native component.

You can communicate to the WebView through the ANE using JS, AS3 events, etc.

If you require to animate the WebView and layer AIR content over you can use the 'screenshot' functionality to capture a BitmapData representation of the WebView. The BitmapData you can then use in your AIR content as a way to animate the WebView. Obviously the WebView is not interactive when you are using a screenshot to animate though.

Hope this clears up your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have other question. I am trying to load the same web page in iOS and Android. In iOS works perfect but in Android the page doesn't load completely, only the text. I am following the simple example so I don't know if there is something else I should take into account regarding development in Android.
Best regards,

Comment: You have to be careful with paths and permissions on Android, make sure your content is somewhere outside the zipped application package in your application storage.

Comment: Just to understand your answer: Do I need to have the content of the web page stored in the storage of the app? We also tested another web pages and we saw that if the web page has this header <!doctype html> the web pages does not load on Android. Is it an issue of the ANE?